# Not able to login to ACR using docker login

Tags: azure, docker, acr

I have certain docker images on the docker server hosted in the corporate network. The docker machine works fine and able to execute all docker commands.

I have created the ACR repository and now want to push these docker images to ACR.
ACR is reachable from docker machine

```
root@artifactory:/home/administrator# curl -Is https://fo25.azurecr.io/v2/
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: openresty
Date: Sat, 04 Apr 2020 12:21:29 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 149
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Docker-Content-Digest
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: WWW-Authenticate
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Link
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Ms-Correlation-Request-Id
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Www-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://fo25.azurecr.io/oauth2/token",service="fo25.azurecr.io"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Ms-Correlation-Request-Id: 354950c2-a4d8-40ac-9b0b-d6f197572284
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
```

still not able to push these images to ACR. here is the command i used to push images and faced the following error

```
root@artifactory:/home/administrator# cat pass | docker login --username fo25 --password-stdin https://fo25.azurecr.io/v2/
Error response from daemon: Get https://fo25.azurecr.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

not sure where is the issue. i have checked everything like username, access keys etc. 
URL is also reachable as we are getting 200 access code.
do i need to increase the timeout period ?

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? Please let me know and give the updates.

Comment: Do you solve the problem or still work on it? I didn't see any updates and you also do not accept it. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-prepare-acr#container-registry-login) link.

I see a similar problem in the corporate network, try different machine or different network.

Comment: the machine which i am using does not have az command line installed so i am using docker login command. i cannot change the network as the docker images are part of this network only. please suggest

Comment: docker file doesn't have any secret information, better you can create a sample application with same docker file and you can try to push that sample in dockerhub and ACR.

Comment: i think you are not getting what i am asking. it is not about dockerfile . i am facing issue about connecting ACR from my corporate network . Please suggest how to resolve

Comment: please suggest. this is blocker

Comment: I mean use similar docker file with sample application then push in ACR from the corporate network and outside network, that is the only way to confirm this is network issue or not.

Answer (score 0):

Its resolved. It was solely issue of Proxy configuration. The proxy URL was pointing to wrong port for the HTTPS connection and that was the issue.

After correcting to right port, docker login was successful